# How to trigger validation bubble

Tags: jquery, html, validation, bootstrap-4

I have a starting form that has a bootstrap 4 form group input button (input with associated button). I am using simple Jquery validation to prompt the user to enter a valid studentid. If a user hits the enter key while the input has focus there is an HTML 5 validation bubble that pops up "Please fill out this field". I am trying (for consistency) to get the button to produce the same behavior. I have tried creating a jquery event and simulating a click event, and several other approaches... Anyone have an idea how to accomplish this?

```
<form id="student-search-form" name="student-search-form" onsubmit="authorizeuser()" class="was-validated" autocomplete="off" autocompletetype="none">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <input id="searchid" name="searchid" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Student ID" aria-label="Student ID" pattern=".{6,8}" autofocus required>
        <span class="input-group-append">
            <button id="go" class="btn btn-success rounded-right" type="button" onclick="triggerenter()">Go!</button>
        </span>
        <div class="invalid-feedback ml-1">Please provide a valid StudentID</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want your button to do exactly? Assuming it should submit the form, you should change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`. It doesn't matter if the form is submitted by a button or a key event, the HTML5 popup should happen in either case.